# If I host a JS file, can I identify what URLs embed it?

Tags: php, javascript

If I host a javascript file on my server that users can embed in their webpages, is it possible to identify the URLS that embedded my file?

I imagine I could only get the user requesting the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure

If you host a JS file, say /js/myscript.js

Don't actually have a script there, have a php file which with a htaccess rule will be served when a request is made for the js

Then in that PHP file, log the referrer, date and whatever else you want, then set the appropriate headers and do a simple import of the js file

```
<?php
// log referrer / date to the database
header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");
include 'therealscript.js';
?>
```

Comment: I don't think "redicting" to the actual JS would be the right thing to do. A client could always cache the redirect, in which case you'll lose these statistics.

Comment: I never mentioned doing a redirect

Answer (score 1):

To be able to know when someone embeds your JS in their site, the JS will need to be able to "phone home" and tell them of the origin site.

While that is not directly possible, one workaround pops to mind : have the JS append a small image to the end of the page, with its `src` set to a php script on your server. The rest is magic.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the client browser, but I imagine most will put the page that includes the js as the referrer, so it would be in your server access log. The PHP method that @cusimar9 mentions would also depend on the client filling in the referrer for you.

Answer (score 0):

> If I host a javascript file on my server that users can embed in their webpages, is it possible to identify the URLS that embedded my file?

`window.location.href` should give you the embedding document's URL. You could send that to your server by, say, loading an image:

```
url = window.location.href;
img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("src", "http://myserver.com/counthit?url="+url);
```

Alternatively, you could catch the `HTTP_REFERER` header on server side.

Always note that both these values can be faked by individual clients. They can't be used for anything security relevant! However, they are fairly reliable for gathering statistical data or for getting an overview of sites that use your hosted script.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hack,
in your javascript file.
create an img element, and assign it a src of your domain.
eg.

```
http://www.mysite.com/getURL.php?theurl=SOME_VALUE;
```

where SOME_VALUE can be calculated easily in javascript like:

```
window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host
```

Some browsers might treat it as unsecure behaviour though.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is browser-dependent, however, the standard specifies an HTTP header that is sent with every HTTP request for assets that are part of a web-page to set in "referrer", and all browsers comply with this standard.
Here's a short explanation:

> http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z14

This header will be sent by most browsers and depending on your web-server - this header can be captured and logged for every request made to this resource.

A more dirty solution will be - since you're running a script - to fire a request to a tracking utility. If I had to take that option, I'd make the tracking utility a server page, and host it in a  tag - this way the server's respond does not have to be an image, but javascript - and for that - an empty string as a reply is good enough, however, to be clean - you can fire from your response a callback function to remove from the DOM the added tracking  tag.

Both ways will pile you with loads of logging, and an advantage of the second is that you can more easily program a little more sophisticated counter then just a piling-up log file, but it can be done with the first way as well (again - the implementation depends on your web server).

However, for that reason - that an embedded script has enormous power on the web-page it runs in and can bring in or change almost anything **regardless to the source of that script** - it is accounted as a bad habit to embed in your page scripts that you do not have control over their content, and because of that - I would not recommend it as a strategy.